# How to exclude specific characters between brackets in regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++, autohotkey

I want to find and remove the exclamation mark in the second and third lines only but retain the exclamations marks in the first line.

```
[some text !]
[some text !
some text !
```

I've tried :

```
(?<!\[.*)(!)(?!.*\])
```

However, look behinds cannot consume any characters.

Comment: What tool/flavor do you use?

Comment: autohotkey or in notepad++

Comment: What about: `[some ! text]` — `(some text !)` — `(some text !` — `some! text` — `!not this one?`, etc.  Also, what should the output be — is it OK to leave spaces that appeared before or after the exclamation mark?  (It is a lot easier if there's no need to pay attention to spacing!)  In other words, you need to be much more precise about when the exclamation mark should be kept and when it should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, replace:

```
(                # Capturing group consisting of
  ^\[            # a square bracket at the beginning of line,
  [^[\]]*        # 0+ non-bracket characters, then
  \]$            # a closing bracket at the end of line,
)                # 
|                # or
!                # a literal '!'
```

with:

```
\1
```

This matches all square-bracketed strings and exclamation marks, but since we're capturing the former and add that back, only the exclamation marks will be removed.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/h18O8k/1).

If the brackets are not guaranteed to be at the beginning/end of line, simply remove `^` and `$`: `(\[[^[\]]*\])|!`. Note that this may match square-bracketed multi-line strings:

```
[some tex!t !]
[som!e text !
!some text !
] ! foobar
```

...becomes:

```
[some tex!t !]
[som!e text !
!some text !
]  foobar
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/h18O8k/2).

To limit the match on one line, add a `\n` to the character class: `(\[[^[\]\n]*\])|!`.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/h18O8k/3).

Alternatively, use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to forgo the first part, as suggested by [bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/u/5527985): `\[[^[\]\n]\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|!`.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ACu6MM/1).

Comment: thanks, this was it!
More simply for my purposes: (\[.*\])|!
the key was to capture any characters within the brackets and then find the exclamation mark.

Comment: `(\[.*\])` [might not](https://regex101.com/r/h18O8k/4) match [as expected](https://regex101.com/r/h18O8k/5).

Comment: Nice answer! Worth to mention, in PCRE even [verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) [could be used (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/ACu6MM/1).

Comment: That's something new to me. Thanks, updated.